# Converting varchar to int in phpMyAdmin returns 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, phpmyadmin, varchar

I have a column for Salary that is formatted as varchar(1000) and I don't have permission to alter the table structure. Some of the data was entered with commas (ex. 58,000) and some without (ex. 52000). Any way that I've tried to cast this field as a numeric value has changed the salaries with commas to 0. What am I doing wrong?

If I do this:

```
SELECT uniqueid, REPLACE(salary,",","") FROM job_offer;
```

I get the person's name and 58000. 
So I would expect that if I do this...

```
SELECT uniqueid, CAST(REPLACE(salary,",","") as unsigned) FROM job_offer;
```

...nothing should change. But it returns 0 for the salary instead of 58000.

I've tried other data types besides unsigned and I've tried using CONVERT too, but still no luck. I've looked online for hours to find and answer, but that has also been unsuccessful.

Ultimately, I'm trying to take an average of the salaries, and this is preventing me from doing so. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: if its just for selection then REPLACE(salary,",","") is more than enough.

Comment: thanks! when I try to take an average of that though, it creates an issue since it's non-numeric

Comment: ah i see I just tried on mysql and seems to be working `select cast(replace('58,000',',','') as UNSIGNED) as salary;` output `58000`

Comment: hmm, could it be that I don't have permissions to use cast? that doesn't seem like it should be an issue

Comment: I dont think so that it could be an issue.

Comment: okay when I try select cast(replace('58,000',',','') as unsigned) from job_offer; it converts it to a number, but once I replace "58,000" with "salary", it returns 0??

Comment: hmm it should work, may be there are null values which is returning 0

Comment: I'm sure that the values aren't null, which is why I'm so confused why it's returning 0

Comment: not sure now I am confused too and cant see a reason for it

Comment: I converted it to char instead and it worked